# How to change the default soundcard in Debian to an external USB?

Tags: debian, drivers, audio, alsa, usb-audio

Running Jessie and `aplay -l` gives me this:

```
**** List of PLAYBACK Hardware Devices ****
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 0: ALC887-VD Analog [ALC887-VD Analog]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 0: PCH [HDA Intel PCH], device 1: ALC887-VD Digital [ALC887-VD Digital]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 1: HDMI [HDA ATI HDMI], device 3: HDMI 0 [HDMI 0]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
card 2: Device [USB Advanced Audio Device], device 0: USB Audio [USB Audio]
  Subdevices: 1/1
  Subdevice #0: subdevice #0
```

The usb card is my only working device (`alsaplayer -o alsa -d hw:2,0 rocknroll.mp3` confirms this)

so I came up with the following /etc/modprobe.d/sound file and restarted pulseaudio:

```
options snd cards_limit=3
alias snd-card-0 snd-1
alias snd-card-1 snd-hdmi
alias snd-card-2 snd-usb
options snd slots=snd_usb_audio,snd_hd_intel,snd-1
```

But still no sound on my system. What am I not doing? I had to create the sound file above as there was none before. So maybe that's an outdated way of doing things.

Comment: Tried `alsamixer` ?

Comment: The `slots` line is the only one you need, and the driver names except `snd-usb-audio` are wrong. Anyway, did the order change? What did you configure in PulseAudio (`pavucontrol`)?

Comment: I didn't configure anything in pavucontrol. And what do I do in alsamixer?

Comment: editing down to slots and restarting pulseaudio did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I am going to put a generic answer here, because this comes up so many times and this has been bothering me for years.

Essentially i've got a system with a Xonar DX soundcard, a sound output on my GPU, and an onboard soundcard on the motherboard.

It's completely random which soundcard gets set as default as it's a race condition during startup. Furthermore i can't blacklist the kernel module for the GPU sound output, because it uses the same snd_hda_intel module as the onboard soundcard, so i can't work out how to disable one, without disabling the other.

The first thing to do is to work out what kernel modules they are using. To do this run the command:

```
lspci -k
```

This will show the kernel modules your pci devices use. If you are using usb devices you need to find out some other way. If lspci isn't install install it using: `apt-get install pciutils`. For USB devices try:

```
lsmod | grep snd
```

May help you narrow it down a bit!

My `lspci -k` output looks like this:

```
...
06:04.0 Multimedia audio controller: C-Media Electronics Inc CMI8788 [Oxygen HD Audio]
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Virtuoso 100 (Xonar DX)
        Kernel driver in use: snd_virtuoso
        Kernel modules: snd_virtuoso
...
0a:00.1 Audio device: NVIDIA Corporation GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller (rev a1)
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. GK208 HDMI/DP Audio Controller
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
...
0c:00.3 Audio device: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD] Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
        Subsystem: ASUSTeK Computer Inc. Family 17h (Models 00h-0fh) HD Audio Controller
        Kernel driver in use: snd_hda_intel
        Kernel modules: snd_hda_intel
...
```

Now, i want the Xonar DX soundcard to be first so I insert the following in sound.conf:

```
# cat /etc/modprobe.d/sound.conf 
options snd cards_limit=3
options snd slots=snd_virtuoso,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_intel
```

After a reboot, the snd_virtuoso (i.e. my xonar dx) comes up first.

Note there's no need whatsoever in this setup for pulse audio. This is purely in terms of alsa.